# How can i display single recent blog post?

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, blog

I need to display my recent blog post under all selected category landing page and selected products left side.

Comment: Which extension are you using for blog?

Comment: AHEADWORKS EXTENSIONS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to your local.xml. This will show the recent posts and categories of blogs to left side of your product page(if product page layout is 2cloumns-left).

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="blog/menu_sidebar" name="left.blog.menu"  after="-">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>aw_blog/menu.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="blog/tags" name="blog_tags" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

You can put condition according to your requirement on blog/menu.phtml or create one new file blog_menu.phtml and put your conditions.

Also if you want to use the same to catagory page then update the handler for category pages

Comment: you mean app/etc/local.xml file?

Comment: No. You can create one local.xml file under your theme layout directory.

Comment: I am added code to : app/design/frontend/default/theme/layout/local.xml -> code : https://justpaste.it/5txvu then i what i need to do.

Comment: No need to do anything now. Check any product which has 2columns-left layout. The recent blogs will show there. If you have enabled cache then flush the cache.

Comment: No, still not working..... May i know the possibilities of error.

Comment: Now you need to debug your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78176/discussion-between-zus-and-sukumar-gorai).